# Powershell Workflow Foreach-Parallel not executing

Tags: powershell, workflow-foundation, azure-powershell

I'm attempting to parallellize some file transfers via the following:

```
Workflow DownloadFiles{
    Write-Output "Beginning workflow."
    foreach -parallel ($dir in $destinations)
    {
        try{
            Write-Output "Copying to to: " $dir
            InlineScript{
                 &"$AzCopyPath" /Source:"$sourceDirectory" /Dest:$dir /SourceKey:$sourceKey /Pattern:"$sourcePattern" 
                Write-Output "Copied to: " $dir
            } 
        }
        catch{
            InlineScript{
                $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
                $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
                Write-Output $dir : $ErrorMessage  $FailedItem -ForegroundColor Red
            }
        }
        Write-Output "Done";
    }

}
```

However the script is ending immediately with no output.  Even if I try this, I get nothing:

```
Workflow DownloadFiles{
    Write-Output "Beginning workflow."
    Write-Output "Done";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you execute your workflow?

Comment: @PetSerAl through Powershell ISE

Comment: I mean which command you use to invoke workflow, like `DownloadFiles param1 param2`.

Comment: @PetSerAl - I'm an idiot.  Though I just typed in `DownloadFiles` at the end, and all I get is `Beginning Workflow`.  Any idea why the innards aren't running?

Comment: I haven't done a lot of workflows, but if I remember right you can't access parent scopes from within a workflow, so you have to pass all of your variables in as parameters into the workflow. Also, consider the workflow like a function, where you define it, and then you have to call it.

Comment: I believe as you are running inline script and foreach-parallel so you must be using psm file and not ps1 file. Write-output does not work in a workflow. Remove all write-output and then give a try.